# scatterplotMatrix with diagonal histogram

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I'm trying to create a scatterplotMatrix for my data, then i tried the code taken from https://livebook.manning.com/book/r-in-action/chapter-11/46

```
  scatterplotMatrix(~ mpg + disp + drat + wt | cyl, data=mtcars,
                  spread=FALSE, diagonal="histogram",
                  main="Scatter Plot Matrix via car Package")
```

then i run it

[image]

the results are different, and no histogram appears in the plot

and a warning appears

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

can you tell me where is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mention the method in a list to `diagonal` like this:

```r
library(car)
#> Loading required package: carData
scatterplotMatrix(~ mpg + disp + drat + wt | cyl, data=mtcars,
                  spread=FALSE, diagonal=list(method ="histogram"),
                  main="Scatter Plot Matrix via car Package")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>